# Best way to increment count views in SPA

Tags: angularjs, backbone.js, ember.js, sails.js, single-page-application

How you increase the counter of page views in SPA?

A separate request? Hook in model, when you download the data?

I work with Ember.js + Sails.js

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count the number of times a view of the frontend application retrieves a particular resource, I would rather add the counter in the controller.